What happened to the rooks? (A monochromatic chess mystery)
Here is a new retrograde chess puzzle! For this one, we are once again using the special monochromatic ruleset, meaning that pieces may only move between squares of the same checkerboard colour. In the game leading to the position below, all four rooks have somehow already been captured. Can you tell how that happened?
For each of the four rooks, can you determine where they were taken and by which piece?


(6+9), FEN: 6n1/2p2pp1/6p1/pp6/k1P5/8/3PPP1P/1q4K1
Monochromatic Chess

Just to clarify: The monochromatic condition also applies to checks, so the white king is currently not in check.
Please provide your reasoning in your answer. I do expect this puzzle to be fairly tricky, but don't let that deter you from giving it a shot. Have fun solving this! :^)

Merely out of curiosity and probably not relevant to the question: with a black queen on b1 and, say, the white king and rook on e1 and h1. Is white allowed to castle? The queen controls f1 but in a monochromatic world does the king even go through this square?

@Albert.Lang Good question! From my interpretation of the rules (and for this puzzle), this is allowed. But I don't know any "official" stance on this tbh.

Answer:

 white Ra1 taken by queen; Rf1 taken by bishop


 black Rg6 taken by pawn; Rd6 taken by pawn

Proof game:

 1. g4 d5 2. b4 Qd6 3. Ba3 Qg3 4. Bc1 Qxg1 5. Ba3 Qg3 6. Bg2 Bf5 7. Be4 Qe5 8. Bd3 Be4 9. O-O Bg2 10. Bc4 Bxf1 11. Bc1 Bg2 12. Qf1 Be4 13. Qh3 Bf5 14. Qb3 Qxa1 15. Bb2 Bg6 16. Bd4 Bf5 17. Bb6 Qd4 18. Bd3 Qc5 19. Bc4 axb6 20. bxc5 Kd7 21. Bd3 Kc6 22. Bc4 Ra4 23. Bd3 Re4 24. Bc4 Re6 25. gxf5 Rg6 26. fxg6 hxg6 27. Qd3 Rh4 28. Qb3 Rd4 29. Qd3 dxc4 30. Qb3 Rd6 31. cxd6 cxb3 32. dxe7 bxa2 33. exf8=Q axb1=Q 34. Qxb8 Kb5 35. Qa7 Ka4 36. Qa5 bxa5 37. c4 b5

Partial reasoning:
Constraints come from:
White must have castled.
The last black squared capture must have been black pawn b6xa5. As this blocks all "natural" ways of capturing the black knight on b8 it forces the promotion of white's b2 pawn.
The black queen is the "wrong" colour, so it must be the promoted d7 (or, theoretically, b7) pawn.
As each promotion requires at least 4 captures on same colour squares (e.p. can be ruled out in this particular puzzle) and there are not many possible capturees available these are strong constraints.
Similarly, since the only candidate for having been captured by the black pawn on g6 is the white g pawn it must have captured at least twice itself.
Both black rooks are captured inside such pawn "chain captures".
Some constraints likely come from there only being limited white moves available towards the end. But I do not have a clear picture how they work. But I suspect it is some subtle timing thing that pins the a1 rook to be captured at a1
EDIT: ok I think I worked it out. The only white pieces capable of waiting moves are the bishops the queen the rooks and the b2 pawn but not before it is promoted. The light squared of these pieces (one bishop one rook and the queen must have been captured before the dark squared rook can be freed.
The b2 pawn must capture in that order the queen, dark squared rook, the e7 pawn, bishop which did not get a chance to leave f8 and, finally, the knight b8. To allow the dark squared rook to get out the white squared rook must have been captured on g6. It can not get there before the white dark squared bishop was captured on b6 and the white b pawn has cleared the 4th rank which it had to enter in order to release the bishop. To make way it has to capture the black queen which is the only black piece that could capture the white dark squared rook, so that must already have happened. Therefore the moment the black rook moves to the king's side on the 4th rank no waiting moves are available for white and black would need a few moves of maneuvering to get its other rook to d6.
These waiting moves can only be provided by the white queen or light squared bishop. So the a1 rook could not have been left out before the black queen is captured.
Fun detail:
The white queen must leave via the king's side because c2-c4 would block the capture path of the d7 pawn. For this to be possible the white f1 rook has to be eliminated first.

Looks good so far, you have found all the right answers! I can also confirm your hunch in the second-to-last paragraph. Once you untangle that, the solution is complete :)

@TimSeifert I've given it a shot.

Very good solution, well done :)
